Snowflake custom OAuth not working with invalid_client error
First it was working, and it showed scope not available error, but now it is showing this error,
I created the integration using the snowflake_oauth_docs and this is my query:
CREATE SECURITY INTEGRATION my_app_oauth
   TYPE = OAUTH
   ENABLED = TRUE
   OAUTH_CLIENT = CUSTOM
   OAUTH_CLIENT_TYPE = 'CONFIDENTIAL'
   OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI = 'https://b54rmx30-8000.inc1.devtunnels.ms/callback/snowflake/'
   OAUTH_ISSUE_REFRESH_TOKENS = TRUE
   OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY = 7776000;

and then I did this DESC SECURITY INTEGRATION my_app_oauth; and this SELECT SYSTEM$SHOW_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRETS('DATAOPSLY_OAUTH');
and I collected the client_id and client_secret
and I'm using django for my oauth, so this is my callback and login view:
def snowflake_login(request):
    # Snowflake OAuth configuration
    snowflake_client_id = 'my_client_id'
    snowflake_client_secret = 'my_secret'
    authorization_url = 'https://<my_account>.snowflakecomputing.com/oauth/authorize'
    token_url = 'https://<my_account>.snowflakecomputing.com/oauth/token'
    redirect_uri = 'https://b54rmx30-8000.inc1.devtunnels.ms/callback/snowflake/'  # Update with your Django callback URL
    scopes = 'openid email profile'  # Adjust scopes as needed

    # Redirect user to Snowflake OAuth authorization URL
    auth_params = {
        'response_type': 'code',
        'client_id': snowflake_client_id,
        'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
        'scope': scopes,
    }
    redirect_url = f"{authorization_url}?{'&'.join([f'{k}={v}' for k, v in auth_params.items()])}"
    return redirect(redirect_url)

def snowflake_callback(request):
    # Handle callback from Snowflake OAuth
    snowflake_client_id = 'my_client_id'
    snowflake_client_secret = 'my_secret'
    token_url = 'https://<my_account>.snowflakecomputing.com/oauth/token'
    redirect_uri = 'https://b54rmx30-8000.inc1.devtunnels.ms/callback/snowflake/'  # Update with your Django callback URL

    # Get authorization code from callback request
    code = request.GET.get('code')
    
    # Exchange authorization code for access token
    token_params = {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': code,
        'client_id': snowflake_client_id,
        'client_secret': snowflake_client_secret,
        'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
    }

    # Make POST request to get access token
    response = requests.post(token_url, data=token_params)
    print("***************response:", response)
    token_data = response.json()
    print("**************token_data:", token_data)

    # Assuming successful response, store token_data as needed (e.g., in session)
    access_token = token_data.get('access_token')
    refresh_token = token_data.get('refresh_token')

    # Example of using the access token to fetch user information
    if access_token:
        headers = {
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        }
        user_info_url = 'https://<my_account>.snowflakecomputing.com/oauth/userinfo'
        user_info_response = requests.get(user_info_url, headers=headers)
        user_info = user_info_response.json()

        # Example: Extract user details from user_info and create/update user in your Django app
        email = user_info.get('email')
        username = user_info.get('username')

        # Logic to authenticate user in Django (create user if not exists, login, etc.)
        # Example:
        # user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(email=email, defaults={'username': username})
        # login(request, user)

        # Redirect user to home or another page after successful login
        return redirect('home')

    # Handle error scenarios if needed
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'error_message': 'Failed to authenticate with Snowflake.'})

I have used this from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
So, my problem is I receive this error:

Error occurred in authorization
OAuth client integration with the given client id is not found.

even when I access the url from DESC SECURITY INTEGRATION my_app_oauth;
Firstly I tried normally and I got an error of scope not applicable or something, then, when I tried creating a new integration suddenly I received this error, don't know how to proceed further!
Can someone please help me!

When using the Snowflake as the OAuth server, the tokens have to be requested as:
Url to get the authorization code:
<OAUTH_AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT>?response_type=code&client_id=&redirect_uri=
Note: We have to URL-encode the client_id and the redirect URI.
Could you please check if you are sending the client ID after encoding?
Refer to the following article which talks about a reference integration to get the token.
Snowflake Oauth Custom

yeah thanks bro, it worked

Please rephrase this (e.g. based on the confirmation you got) to not inlcude a question. Even rhetorical questions (and this is not one) confuse the more doggedly minded users and posts like that risk getting into (undeserved) trouble for not looking like an answer according to [answer].
